# Filling in a pdf form with aspose

Tags: pdf, aspose, pdf-form

I am trying to use Aspose to set the values of fields in a pdf.  **This pdf works fine in ITextSharp.**  That is the main frustration I am experiencing.

Here's my code

```
string outputPdf = String.Format(@"C:\PDF\output\test{0:dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss}.pdf", DateTime.Now);
string inputPdf = @"C:\PDF\application.pdf";

Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form form = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form(inputPdf, outputPdf);

form.FillField("MY_FIELD", "Test Value");

form.FlattenAllFields();
form.Save();
```

the line `Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form form = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form(inputPdf, outputPdf);` is causing an error.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's the stacktrace

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      Aspose.Pdf.EmbeddedFileCollection.( node, Hashtable hash) +57
>      Aspose.Pdf.EmbeddedFileCollection..ctor(Document document) +161
>      Aspose.Pdf.Document.() +58
>      Aspose.Pdf.Document.(Stream input, String password) +181
>      Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form..ctor(String srcFileName, Stream destStream) +92

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted on their forums and it appears Aspose.Pdf 6.0.0 has known bugs due to a project merge between Aspose.Pdf and Aspose.Pdf.Kit.  I am unable to open a Document or access the form in 6.0.0, so I grabbed Aspose.Pdf.Kit 5.6.0 and I was able to make it work.

```
Aspose.Pdf.Kit.Form form = new Aspose.Pdf.Kit.Form(inputPdf, outputPdf);

form.FillField("MyField", "Some Value");
```

Hope that helps anyone else who tries to use their software.  After I did that, everything works fine for my demo version.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Aspose.Pdf for .NET 6.2.0](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx)? Our team is also reviewing the upcoming version 6.3.0 which will be published in a week. Please try the latest one. If you still find any such issue please report it along with the input PDF file in [Aspose.Pdf forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.pdf-product-family/20/showforum.aspx) so our team could help you resolve this issue.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.